# VBA Excel get first line data from website table

Tags: vba, excel, web-crawler

I am using VBA Excel to crawl some data from the internet. 
The link is :

http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BOS/BOS199004090.shtml

I would like to extract these line, with each element in a different cell:

Jack Morris, L (0-1)    6.2 7   5   2   3   3   0   2.7 31  95  52  31  7   14  8   17  5   0   46          -0.252  0.62    -2.1

My Code:

```
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Top = 0
objIE.Left = 0
objIE.Width = 800
objIE.Height = 600
objIE.Visible = True

objIE.Navigate ("http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BOS/BOS199004090.shtml")

Do
DoEvents

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
    GoTo j:

    End If
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

item = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("suppress_csv sortable stats_table now_sortable")(0).getElementsByTagName("td")(0)
```

I tried different combinations to extract my *item* but nothing seems to work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can be a lot easier with Power Query if your version of Excel supports it

Comment: Your project would be so much better if you focused on the St Louis Cardinals :P

Comment: STL are on my list too :P ... Once I can figure out this mess.. anything else will get a whole lot easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:
m going from 0 to whatever....

```
Set tbl = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("overthrow table_container")(2).getElementsByTagName("tr")(1).getElementsByTagName("td")(m).innerText
```